# Change log file with index

Tags: python, string, list, file, python-2.7

I have a file which contains a user:

```
Sep 15 04:34:31 li146-252 sshd[13326]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42579 ssh2
```

Trying to use index method for string to edit the user within the file. So far I am able to print the user but now to delete and put in the new user.

```
newuser = 'PeterB'
with open ('test.txt') as file: 
        for line in file.readlines(): 
                lines = line.split() 
                string = ' '.join(lines)
                print string.index('user')+1
```

Comment: Did you try `line.replace('user', 'PeterB')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to update the file contents? If so, you can update the user name, but you will need to rewrite the file, or write to a second file (for safety):

```
keyword = 'user'
newuser = 'PeterB'
with open('test.txt') as infile, open('updated.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        words = line.split()
        try:
            index = words.index(keyword) + 1
            words[index] = newuser
            outfile.write('{}\n'.format(' '.join(words)))
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            outfile.write(line)    # no keyword, or keyword at end of line
```

Note that this code assumes that each word in the output file is to be separated by a single space.

Also note that this code does not drop lines that do not contain the keyword in them (as do other solutions).

---

If you want to preserve the original whitespace, regular expressions are very handy, and the resulting code is comparatively simple:

```
import re

keyword = 'user'
newuser = 'PeterB'
pattern = re.compile(r'({}\s+)(\S+)'.format(keyword))

with open('test.txt') as infile, open('updated.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(pattern.sub(r'\1{}'.format(newuser), line))
```

Comment: Oh right, so is it possible to just overwrite the user and let everythign else be. You have to overwrite the whole file or create a second file.

Comment: In general it is inefficient to update the file in place because the new text might not have the same length as the original text, so you'd need to shuffle the rest of the file along to make room for the new text (or reduce the size if the new text is smaller) . This is messy and error prone, and if you get it wrong you could trash the original file. It's more efficient and safer to use an intermediate file, and to replace the original file once you are certain that the update was successful.

Comment: @user3270211: I have added a regex based solution that might be better for you, especially if you want to leave the original whitespace intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the names in your log, here is how.

```
file = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
new_file = []
for line in file.readlines():  # read the lines
    line = (line.split(' '))
    line[10] = 'vader'  # edit the name
    new_file.append(' '.join(line))  # store the changes to a variable

file = open('tmp.txt', 'w')  # write the new log to file
[file.writelines(line) for line in new_file]
```